# â€‹ characters appear in code after pasteing it from jsFiddle 

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

Ok here is what im doing. I am making a drop down menu which based on user selection will show the correct form. Now I am able to get it working here http://jsfiddle.net/13lackHawk/Vhbw8/ but when I apply it to an actual page it doesn't work. I don't know what im doing wrong here. It seems straight forward. Could anyone help me determine the problem? It's been bugging me for the past couple days.

Here is a live version of this.

http://panel.dev.adkgamers.com/site/scripts/forms.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove this from your `script` code at line 24: `â€‹`

**jsFiddle sometimes injects the `â€‹`** characters at the end of the code inside it's *script window*. Get rid of it by manually deleting the line in question and rewrite it.

http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/18239/jquery-script-strange-issue/p1

Comment: You have two in there. FYI: There is a jsfiddle bug concerning this.

Comment: I don't see it in the code at all. I do see it on the page. the 'â€‹' is not in the script at all. That shows up once the page loaded. Thats the problem.

Comment: @AndrewMurray there are sometines some hidden characters that are taken up from online editors as pointed out by Dan. You should delete your last line manually and rewrite it character by character.